# Outputting/printing 6 numbers per line from a loop

Tags: java, loops, system.out

I'm trying to write a very basic code that takes takes a number (done by manually editing the code (i.e. no scanner allowed) and then prints all of it's multiples up to a certain max (also something imputed manually in the code). I have the code working for the loops, values, etc.  - it's just that we have to include 2 ways to print it. One way is easy, with each number on a new line. The other way is much harder - each line has 6 numbers, right intended, separated by a few spaces. I know that `%(x/y/z/a/b/c)f` will print strings/ints/doubles/etc. Right justified with spacing based on the `x/y/z/a/b/c`, but I don't know how to automatically start a new line after 6 numbers.

```
import java.util.*;
public class IncrementMax
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int maxvalue = 200; // these top 2 values have to be adjusted to suit the program to your needs
        int incvalue = 5;
        int increment = incvalue; 
        int max = 200;

        System.out.println("I will print the multiples of " + increment + ", up to " + max + ". Do you want each number on a different line (y/n)?");
        String yesno = sc.next();

        if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            for(increment=incvalue; increment<(max+incvalue); increment=increment+incvalue)
                System.out.println(increment);
        }
        else if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            for (increment=incvalue; increment<(max+incvalue); increment=increment+incvalue)
                System.out.print(increment + ". ");
        }
        else
            System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

Here's the code I have so far.

Comment: You need an if condition in the for loop that prints a new line every time you have printed out 6 lines. Hint: modulus operator

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis to think I was already typing out exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively simple use of the `%` operator:

```
for (increment = incvalue; increment < max + incvalue; increment += incvalue) {
    System.out.print(increment);
    if (increment % (incvalue * 6) == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it.                              However, I'm having issues tracing this to see how it works (so I can adapt it if need be to future code). I get that what you're testing is if the int increment is divisible by 6 (I assume something that somehow only happens every 6 lines) but what I don't see is how you are making the increment divisible by 6 perfectly (seeing as I've now tried it with other numbers and it still works).

Comment: It works because `increment` is initialized to `incvalue`. To do any number `n`, use `increment % (incvalue * n)`.